# Use Excel pivot table instead of SUMIFS

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot, pivot-table, powerpivot

I have a fairly simple Excel table. Currently, I am using SUMIFS to get my results.

I made the pictures in Google spreadsheets, so the formulas are displayed in English, however, in reality, I use MS Excel.

[image: Solution with sumifs]

My current solution with Pivot tables is using 4 different Pivot tables. I need to combine these 4 Pivots into only 1. I know how to use calculated fields, etc. but I still cannot figure out how to use only 1 pivot table.

[image: Solution with 4 pivots]

The first pivot table is using 1 filter (crop 2024), the remaining 3 pivots are using 2 filters (crop 2024, [GS/AM/MV]).

Ultimately I would need the percentages to be calculated in the pivot table itself, but I know how to do that with calculated fields. Is my task possible with pivot tables?

**EDIT**:
Example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Hn8wdcfNlMLNZNgDnFAJfYJ2g1OIW3rKGvoacHU5xrQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: *Is my task possible with pivot tables?* It can probably be done using `Power Pivot` or `Power Query`. If you need further assistance, be aware that your screenshot of data is virtually useless for doing proper troubleshooting. It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet. One can try an OCR program, or manually enter it. Having to do either of these is discouraging to those who might assist you. To make the data useful **edit your question** to post it as **text** (which can be copy/pasted), perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thank you very much for your answer. I have provided an example sheet. I am open to solutions other then simple Pivot tables, however, my main focus would be to use simple pivots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use pivot tables:

the key is to combine filter and sum:

=sum(filter('Field area (ha)',('Crop in 2024'<>"Alfalfa")))

and to make sure the calculated field is not set to summarize by sum.

example sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D1zmLJckwJynspTs1z-cv83DziOLxedxcnkZNfZuFpg/edit?usp=sharing

unfortunately, i wasn't able to grasp the second set of sumifs, but I guess with the formula it should be easy to implement it.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I try to implement this, it only gives me an error. I have provided an example sheet in the question.

Comment: Now, I managed to make it work! If there are any other solutions, I am more than open to them, so please let me know. I am interested in Power Pivot and Power Query as well.

Comment: Is there any way to make it work with a Pivot table but using an earlier version of Excel? I believe this one would only work with Office 365 Excel.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do that using Power Query:
*If your real data has multiple years, you may want to group by years as well as by Company*

```
let

//Read in the tables
//Then combine them
    Source1 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Table1 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source1,{
        {"Company", type text}, {"Field ID", Int64.Type}, {"Field area (ha)", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Crop in 2024", type text}, {"GS", Int64.Type}, {"AM", Int64.Type}, {"MV", Int64.Type}}),
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    Table2 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{
        {"Company", type text}, {"Field ID", Int64.Type}, {"Field area (ha)", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Crop in 2024", type text}, {"GS", Int64.Type}, {"AM", Int64.Type}, {"MV", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Combined Tables" = Table.Combine({Table1,Table2}),

//Group by Company
// then filter by conditions and compute the percentages
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Table1, {"Company"}, {
        {"result", (t)=>
            let 
                alfalfa= List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(t, each ([Crop in 2024]<>"Alfalfa"))[#"Field area (ha)"]),
                #"alfalfa GS" = List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(t, each 
                    ([Crop in 2024]<>"Alfalfa") and [GS]<>null )[#"Field area (ha)"]),
                #"alfalfa AM" = List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(t, each 
                    ([Crop in 2024]<>"Alfalfa") and [AM] <> null )[#"Field area (ha)"]),
                #"alfalfa MV" = List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(t, each 
                    ([Crop in 2024]<>"Alfalfa") and [MV]<>null )[#"Field area (ha)"]),
                AM = #"alfalfa AM"/alfalfa,
                MV = #"alfalfa MV"/alfalfa
            in 

            //combine computations into a Table
                Table.FromRecords(
                    {Record.FromList({AM,MV},{"AM","MV"})}),type table[AM=Percentage.Type,MV=Percentage.Type]
        }}),
    #"Expanded result" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "result", {"AM", "MV"})
in
    #"Expanded result"
```

***Your tables***
[image]

***Results***
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is interested in seeing a dynamic array-based solution for Office 365...

Use the following formula in cell `I4` to create a single-cell report:

```
=LET(
comp, A1:A16, list, UNIQUE(DROP(comp, 1)),
crop, D1:D16, criteria, TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(IF(ISBLANK(J2), {"*","="}, J2), ",")),
area, C1:C16, data, E1:G16,
rows, ROWS(list), cols, COLUMNS(data),
totArea, BYROW(list, LAMBDA(r,
   SUM(SUMIFS(area, comp, r, crop, criteria)))),
byData, MAKEARRAY(rows, cols, LAMBDA(r,c,
   SUM(SUMIFS(area, comp, INDEX(list, r), crop, criteria, INDEX(data,, c), ">0")))),
pctArea, MAKEARRAY(rows, cols, LAMBDA(r,c,
   IFERROR(INDEX(byData, r, c)/INDEX(totArea, r), 0))),
array1, VSTACK(INDEX(comp, 1), list, "Total"),
array2, VSTACK("Total "&INDEX(area, 1), totArea, SUM(totArea)),
array3, VSTACK(INDEX(data, 1, 0)&" "&INDEX(area, 1), byData, BYCOL(byData, LAMBDA(c, SUM(c)))),
array4, IFERROR(VSTACK(TEXTSPLIT(REPT("% of Total,", cols), ",",, TRUE), pctArea, ""), ""),
col_nums, TOROW(WRAPCOLS(SEQUENCE(cols*2), cols)),
HSTACK(array1, array2, CHOOSECOLS(HSTACK(array3, array4), col_nums))
)
```

**OR**, if your system separator is a semi-colon instead of a comma, please try:

```
=LET(
comp; A1:A16; list; UNIQUE(DROP(comp; 1));
crop; D1:D16; criteria; TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(IF(ISBLANK(J2); {"*";"="}; J2); ","));
area; C1:C16; data; E1:G16;
rows; ROWS(list); cols; COLUMNS(data);
totArea; BYROW(list; LAMBDA(r;
   SUM(SUMIFS(area; comp; r; crop; criteria))));
byData; MAKEARRAY(rows; cols; LAMBDA(r;c;
   SUM(SUMIFS(area; comp; INDEX(list; r); crop; criteria; INDEX(data;; c); ">0"))));
pctArea; MAKEARRAY(rows; cols; LAMBDA(r;c;
   IFERROR(INDEX(byData; r; c)/INDEX(totArea; r); 0)));
array1; VSTACK(INDEX(comp; 1); list; "Total");
array2; VSTACK("Total "&INDEX(area; 1); totArea; SUM(totArea));
array3; VSTACK(INDEX(data; 1; 0)&" "&INDEX(area; 1); byData; BYCOL(byData; LAMBDA(c; SUM(c))));
array4; IFERROR(VSTACK(TEXTSPLIT(REPT("% of Total,"; cols); ",";; TRUE); pctArea; ""); "");
col_nums; TOROW(WRAPCOLS(SEQUENCE(cols*2); cols));
HSTACK(array1; array2; CHOOSECOLS(HSTACK(array3; array4); col_nums))
)
```

The primary function used in this method is `SUMIFS()`, which returns the total "*Field area (ha)*" based on the "*Crop in 2024*" criteria input in cell `J2`. The criteria can either be a single value or multiple values separated by commas, and will also accept wildcard characters, including `* ? ~`, as well as comparison operators `<>` for "does not equal". If the criteria is left blank, it will return the total area for all crops using `{"*","="}` to find all text values of any length, plus any blank cells.

**Example 1:** Multiple Criteria, plus Conditional Formatting Rules

[image: single_cell_report.png]

As shown in the screenshot above, three simple conditional formatting rules have been used to format the dynamic results. Each column is formatted with left and right borders, the "*% of Total*" columns are formatted as percentages with 2 decimal places and grey shading, and the header and total rows are formatted with bold font, plus top and bottom borders.

**Example 2:** Single Criteria ("does not equal") vs Blank Criteria ("ALL")

[image: single_cell_report2.png]